# Add a background color to the clicked button only

Tags: javascript, html

Continuing my previous post, this time I need to add a background color to the button when clicked.

I tried a `btn\[i\].style.background ="#000000"` but without success.

```
<script>
const btns = document.getElementById("container");
const textBtn = [ "Item 1", "Item 2",  "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8", "Item 9", "Item 10"]
for(i=0; i <textBtn.length;i++){
  btns.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<button class="allbuttons" value="${textBtn[i]}">${textBtn[i]}</button>`);
}

const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".allbuttons")
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.target.value;  
  btn[i].style.background ="#000000";       
});
}
</script>
```

```
<div id="container"></div>
<h2 class="allbuttons" id="result">Item 1</h2>
```

Comment: "SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement" - maybe fix that first.

Comment: `event.target.("value")` is wrong, and you have no `result` element.

Comment: Sorry for the errors in the post, I added the content you say, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it.

1. Cache the elements up-front, and add *one* listener to the `container` element. We can use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch events from the container's child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM which means we don't have to attach listeners to each button.
2. Instead of updating the container element on each loop iteration build an array of HTML and update the element *once*. You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this. Just make sure you join the array of strings into one HTML string at the end.
3. Use CSS. When a child element of `container` is clicked we call the `handleClick` function which checks to see that the element was a button element. We update the textContent of `result`, and then [add the "black" class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to the button.

```js
// Cache the elements
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const result = document.getElementById('result');

// Add one listener to the container
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

const textBtns = [ 'Item 1', 'Item 2',  'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6', 'Item 7', 'Item 8', 'Item 9', 'Item 10'];

// `map` over the array to produce a joined array of HTML strings
const html = textBtns.map(btn => {
  return `
    <button
      class="allbuttons"
      value="${btn}"
    >${btn}</button>
  `;
}).join('');

// Set the HTML of the container once
container.innerHTML = html;

// Check to see that the clicked element is
// a button, and then update the textContent of `result`
// remove all the "black" classes from the buttons,
// and add a "black" class to the clicked button.
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    result.textContent = e.target.value;
    const buttons = container.querySelectorAll('button');
    buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('black'));
    e.target.classList.add('black');
  }
}
```

```css
.black { background-color: black; }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<h2 class="allbuttons" id="result">Item 1</h2>
```

Comment: this is fantastic, it worked perfectly. If in another case, how do I make the changed color remain only on the last button clicked without the others also changing?

Comment: I add 2 extra lines to the function. The first grabs all the buttons in the container, and the second removes the black classe from each of them. @MauricioRios (I think that's what you meant).